# What happen if record separator and field separator are the same

Tags: awk

In `awk`, what happen if record separator `RS` and field separator `FS` are the same?

How can I tell fields from records?

Comment: You could try it...

Answer (score 5):

Record separator `RS` wins -- takes precedence -- because `awk` needs to determine what is a record first, then breaking the record into fields.

See [the `awk` description section in spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_03) for the complete process.

Example:

```
$ printf '1 2' | awk 'BEGIN{RS = FS = " "};{print $0, NF}'
1 1
2 1
```

With only *one line* of input, `awk` saw *two* records because `RS` is space. `NF` shows us that there's only one field in each record.

In this case, *record* and *field* are identical and can be used interchangeably.